# enviar post a Python desde JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, formularios, post

**Iniciar archivo Python desde post por medio de JavaScript**

> No se inicia mi archivo Python.
> Tengo un formulario que envía un post a un archivo Python.
> El archivo Python no se ejecuta.
> El post se envía correctamente pero no se inicia el archivo Python.

Explicación a fondo del programa:
Tengo un formulario:

```
<div id="agrrergar_panel" style="display: block;">
 <form method="post" id="Formulario">
   <input type="panel" id="panel_agregado" name="panel_add" value="Panel">
   <input type="submit" id="submit_boton" value="Crear">          
 </form>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al rellenar el formulario le daremos al botón "crear" el cual enviara un post con el valor de input que hemos escrito anteriormente.

```
<script>
$('#Formulario').submit(function(){
   event.preventDefault();
   $.post("Archivo_python.py", $(this).serialize());
   event.preventDefault();
   });
</script>
```

Al pulsar el botón se enviara el post y se activara el archivo Python como vemos en la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Pero el archivo Python no se ejecuta.**

Se envía el valor del input pero no se ejecuta el programa Python.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo Python**
El archivo Python es el que vemos a continuación
El programa Python envía el valor del formulario a un Topic mqtt:

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish #libreria  mqtt
import cgi #libreria para recivir el post
form = cgi.FieldStorage()#cojemos el valor del post
name_cambiado = form["panel_add"].value#aqui guardamos el nombre del panel enviado desde el post

print(name_cambiado)#imprimimos para ver si se hizo correctamente la transferencia 

#enviamos valor del formulario a un topic mqtt
broker_address = "localhost" #ip del mqtt

#topic a donde enviamos el valor del formulario
topic_id = "Panel/id" #topic de la id del panel
topic_name = "Panel/name" # topic del nombre del panel

nombre_pnale_nmsg = name_cambiado # mensaje del formulario que hemos seleccionado en el input 
id_pnale_nmsg = "Panel prueba" #id del panel prueba

msgs = [{'topic': topic_id, 'payload': id_pnale_nmsg},#enviamos el al topic id la id de nuestro panel en este caso "Panel prueba"
(topic_name, nombre_pnale_nmsg, 0, False)] #enviamos al topic de nombre de panel el valor que hemos puesto en el input del formulario

publish.multiple(msgs, hostname=broker_address)# publicamos a los Topics
```

El post aunque se envía no se ejecuta el archivo Python
[image: Vista previa del archivo Python en la red al ser llamado desde un post]
En respuesta de red del post veo que se ve igual que en el apartado de vista previa.
[image: RESPUESTA del post]

Hice varias pruebas para descartar errores.
Observe que el envió de valores a Topics se hacían correctamente.
El servido tiene instalado Python y sus respectivas librerías, no se cual podría ser el error del porque no se ejecuta el archivo Python.
Agradezco de antemano vuestra ayuda.

Comment: No debes poner `post("Archivo_python.py",..)` javascript no tiene la posibilidad de ejecutar archivos locales ni del lado del backend, debes colocar la ruta

Comment: Como dice Christian, no puedes enviar un POST a un archivo así nomás. Tiene que haber un servidor http corriendo que exponga una ruta. Para eso puedes usar algo como [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)